# How to implement a DateTime entity property to set always DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, properties

I've read a bunch about auto implemented properties but I still don't quite get it. I have and entity:

```
 public class News
    {
        public int NewsId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I don't want the user to set date himself every time a new entity of `News` type is created. I want the record to be saved automatically with the datetime it's created. Thinking about it I suggest that it's enough to just modify the `set` for my property to something like :

```
public DateTime Date 
{
  get;
  set
  {
    Date = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

But reading about the topic I saw that the standard way is to create private variable and use it instead in the implementation. That's where I get a little bit lost.

```
private DateTime _date = null;
public DateTime Date
{
```

Well I'm not sure for the getter and setter implementations. It seems reasonable to have something like : `set { _date = DateTime.Now;}` and I have no idea how to deal with the `get` part since I want this data to be fetched from the database so something like : `get {return _date;} doesn't make much sense to me even though almost every example with auto implemented`set` returns the private variable. But I think that if the property is an entity this is not making a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ways to return the current date:

```
 public DateTime Date { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
```

or

```
 public class News
 {
    public News()
    {
       Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
 }
```

The first one will always return the current date/time, even if that instance was created some time ago. The second one will return the date/time the instance was created. Both prevent the user from setting that Date value.

Comment: Since it's property of an entity, I will need to be able to show the time of creation (as you can see from the name, it's a `News` table). So when I get the date I need the database date, but when I set the date, that means I create new entity/news I want to set the date of the entity creation. So I guess second approach?

Comment: @Leron - if some code can set the date (retrieval from database) and other code not ("client" side code), that's a problem. You might be able to use an other constructor to set the date, but then you have to write the database-to-entity code yourself.

Comment: I see what you mean. If I understood you right when I query for a record the date will be always override with the DateTime.Now. So it's easier just to set the date in the code where the others properties are set instead of looking for a way to move the logic to the entity?

Comment: @Leron - correct. You could still in the constructor provide a default value (DateTime.Now), for the new newsitems.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a constructor to your class and then initialize there your property.

```
public class News
{

   // properties goes here

   public News()
   {
       Date=DateTime.Now;
   }

}
```

A far better constructor would be the following

```
public News(int newsId, string title, string content)
{
    NewsId=newsId;
    Title=title;
    Content=content;
    Date=DateTime.Now;
}
```

That way you could create an object of type News in a single line of code.

```
News news = new News(1,"title1","whatever");
```

Comment: Hi. What is this `value` variable I've searched but I couldn't find explanation on how exactly its created and used. Seems like something I can use right away when implement a custom getter/setter but I really don't get the difference between `Date = DateTime.Now` and `value = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @Leron The contextual keyword value is used in the set accessor in ordinary property declarations. I used false before. Please look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a1khb4f8.aspx

Comment: But you've changed it by moving the logic in the constructor. Is that better, or because I've asked how to do it using my `Date` property?

Comment: @Leron, I think that the are two ways to do this. The first is the above the second is that Hans suggested. It's a matter of your personal opinion rather that better implementation in this case.

Comment: the NewsId is auto generated property in the database. The problem is how to set the property automatically when entity is saved but when I query to get the date from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't touch the getter and setter! They are auto generated from a template and will be overridden every once and a while. Instead, **as you might have noticed the generated entities are declared partially**, create a partial class and declare a constructor there that sets the _date or Date of you r entity to `DateTime.Now` on construction (just as you desired).

```
public partial class News
{
  public News()
  {
    this.Date = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure I understand you. I haven't written this but it's `Code First` workflow so all the entities are written by me. I've seen partial classes for entities but used with `Database First` workflow where the entities are auto generated. What's the point to have my own `News` entity and then add partial class just to add a constructor?

Comment: Ah I get it! But then you could easily set the date to DateTime.Now in your constructor as others mentioned as well.